# Why can virtual System.Object members be called on unboxed value types (which have no base class)?

Tags: command-line-interface, cil, value-type, boxing, virtual-functions

Consider this IL fragment (which was generated by Microsoft's C# compiler):

```
.class public sequential ansi sealed beforefieldinit Foo
       extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{ … }

.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] valuetype Foo foo)

  ldloca.s          foo                                                   // ?
  constrained. Foo                                                        // ?
  callvirt          instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()   // ?
  pop
  ret
}
```

I would like to know exactly what is going on in the three lines marked `// ?`: How is it possible that a virtual method (`System.Object`'s `ToString`) is called on a *unboxed* value type, which (according to section I.8.9.7 of the CLI specification) has no base type at all?

My current, incomplete understanding is this:

- `ldloca.s foo` results in a transient pointer (`*`) to the local variable `foo` (which contains an unboxed value of type `valuetype Foo`) which in this case, according to section I.12.3.2.1 of the CLI specification, can be used where managed pointers (`&`) are expected.
- This `*` pointer will act as the **this** pointer for the method call. This appears to be legal because it can act as a managed pointer (`&`) here. The CLI standard mentions this possibility in section I.8.9.7.
- The `constrained. Foo` prefix is there to prevent boxing the `valuetype Foo` value to a `boxed Foo` object.

But the main question remains: Why can a virtual method be called on a unboxed value that does not inherit that virtual method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible that a virtual method `System.Object.ToString` is called on a unboxed value type, which (according to section I.8.9.7 of the CLI specification) has no base type at all?

I'm confused by the question. What does having or not having a base type have anything to do with it?

> I would like to know exactly what is going on in the three lines

The key is the `constrained` prefix. The documentation -- Partition III section 2.1 -- is pretty straightforward. In the documentation we have a type of a receiver `thisType`, a managed pointer to that type `ptr`, and a `constrained.callvirt` of `method`. The rules are:

> 1. If `thisType` is a reference type then `ptr` is dereferenced and passed as the `this` pointer to the `callvirt` of `method`
> 2. If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` implements `method` then `ptr` is passed unmodified as the `this` pointer to a `call` of `method` implemented by `thisType`
> 3. If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` does not implement method then
>      `ptr` is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the `this` pointer to the `callvirt` of `method`

In your example point (3) applies. The type `Foo` is a value type, it does not implement the method `ToString`, so it is boxed and the method (provided by a base class) is called with the reference to the box as `this`.

Suppose we had int.ToString. Then point (2) applies. The type is `int`, it is a value type, and `int` implements an override of `System.Object.ToString()`.  So the managed pointer to the `int` becomes the `this` of the call to `ToString`. The unnecessary boxing is thereby elided. (And if `ToString` mutated the `int` then the mutation would happen on the variable given as the receiver, not on the boxed copy.)

> Why can a virtual method be called on a unboxed value that does not inherit that virtual method?

The question at hand is whether or not the method is *implemented*, as is called out in the documentation I quoted above. What does inheritance have to do with it?

A question you did not ask but this is a nice place to answer it:

> Should I always implement ToString on my value types?

Well, I don't know about *always*, but it certainly is a good idea to do so because (1) the default implementation of `ToString` is dismal, and (2) by implementing it on your value types you can manage to elide the boxing penalty any time the method is called directly.

> Does the same go for other virtual methods of object?

Yep. And there are good reasons to make your own equality and hashing in value types anyways. The default value type equality can sometimes be unexpected.

> I note that GetType is not virtual. Is that relevant?

Yes; not being virtual means it cannot be overridden in a value type, which means that calling `GetType` on any value type always boxes it. Of course, if you have an unboxed value type in hand then *you don't need to call `GetType`* because you already know what its type is at compile time!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then (3) applies in my question: I am calling `foo.ToString()` (if you allow me that brief usage of C# syntax). `foo` has the type `valuetype Foo`, which is a value type and does not implement `ToString` (because I have not defined that method myself, nor does `valuetype Foo` have any base type from which it could inherit `ToString`). So according to what you say, the value in `foo` is boxed to a value of type `boxed Foo`, which inherits from `System.ValueType`, which has a `ToString` implementation. Do you agree?

Comment: @stakx: Whoops, I misread your example. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @stakx: Yes, you've summed it up nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I will now review [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031902/240733) to [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1978589/240733). I want to find the spot where the C# language specification and CLI standard differ, so that I can understand why you thought my CLI-based answer not applicable in a C# context.

Comment: @stakx: I think the place they differ that is relevant to your question is that the idea that the "boxed int" and "unboxed int" are different types simply does not exist in C#. A type is a *fact that can be logically deduced about an expression* and the C# type system never logically deduces "this thing is a boxed int". It might deduce that an expression is of type object, but never "object that is a boxed int".

Comment: @EricLippert: If one has two generic storage locations of type `class,IFoo` and `struct,IFoo`, the former will hold something that can be be referred to by an `IFoo` reference but the latter will hold something that cannot (a cast to `IFoo` would yield a reference to a *different* object that is initialized to the same value); I would say the storage locations hold different kinds of things, whether or not C# chooses to recognize the difference.