# By-value and by-reference distinction between List<T> and Array for custom struct and built-in structs (like Int32)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, struct, indexer

I know there is a small but important distinction between using indexers with List and Array. Array returns the reference for the member, whereas List copies the member value. Where I can't wrap my head around is this rule works perfectly for custom structs, but not for built-in structs like Int32.

```
List<int> numbers;

List<Mutable> mutablesList; 
Mutable[] mutablesArray;

public struct Mutable
{
    public int X;
}

numbers[0]++; // OK
mutablesArray[0].X++; //OK
mutablesList[0].X++ //Compiler error
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any plausible explanation on this issue.

Comment: It works to use `++` for custom structs also if you have defined a `++` operator directly on the struct https://dotnetfiddle.net/XyIqqa

Comment: "I can't find any plausible explanation on this issue.". Hit F1 on the error the explanation is the first paragraph with an example fitting your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612

Comment: @Ralf my question is not about why I can't modify a struct on a collection. I'm curious about the difference between array and collection indexers' different behavior when it comes to custom struct vs built-in struct. Int32 is struct right? I can modify it directly when accessed with an indexer in List, but not the same with custom struct. I'd like to learn the reason behind this implementation detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do structs need to be boxed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978589/why-do-structs-need-to-be-boxed)

Answer (score 2):

An array is a collection of variables that are named by their index into the array. So just like

```
Mutable a;
a.X++;
```

is reasonable,

```
mutablesArray[0].X++;
```

is reasonable.

On the other hand, a `List<T>` (or other collection) is a collection of objects (which are references for reference types, and values for value types). So

```
numbersList[0]++;
```

Is equivalent to

```
numbersList[0] = numbersList[0] + 1;
```

which is reasonable as it replaces an element of the collection.

Consider it interpreted something like

```
numbersArray.this_set(0, numbersArray.this_get(0) + 1);
```

But

```
mutablesList[0].X++;
```

attempts to modify an anonymous temporary `struct` that is a copy of the list member, which can be interpreted like:

```
mutablesList.this_get(0).X = mutablesList.this_get(0).X + 1;
```

This is different from what you are doing with the `List<int>`, where you are actually replacing the entire value item (e.g. `int`) with a new value item. This will also work with `Mutable`:

```
mutablesList[0] = new Mutable { X = mutablesList[0].X + 1 };
```

is perfectly valid and works correctly.

Consider creating a method that returns a `struct`:

```
public static T StructCopy<T>(T m) where T : struct => m;
```

Then using the method is analogous to referring to the returned value from indexing the `List<Mutable>`:

```
StructCopy(m).X++;
StructCopy(m).X = StructCopy(m).X + 1;
```

In both cases, the compiler gives an error stating the return value of `StructCopy` isn't a variable. Neither is the return value of `List<T>.this[]`.

It may help to realize the compiler doesn't special case a `struct` with a single member. If `Mutable` had a second member, `public int Y`, then `mutablesList[0].X++;` is an attempt to change part of the structure by modifying the copy, which isn't useful and thus errors.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't get the different behavior by List<int>! Shouldn't it behave like the custom struct like my example, Mutable? I'm trying to replace a member of the List collection which holds value type Int32. Why doesn't compiler treat Int32 in this case as "an anonymous temporary struct that is a copy of the list member" like you suggested?

Comment: @MehmetAliDuran I tried to explain a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access `mutablesList[0]`, .Net will call the indexer's get accessor to load the element on to the stack first. A get accessor is just a method, so it always makes a copy of that element.

When you try to access an array element, .Net has several made-to-order instructions to do the job, especially these two: [`ldelem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelem?view=net-7.0) and [`ldelema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema?view=net-7.0)

`ldelema` will load the address of the element instead of the element itself.

The compiler will intelligently choose the best instruction to use.

For expression `mutablesArray[0].X++` or `var x = mutablesArray[0].X`, the compiler chooses to use `ldelema`, this allows it to modify the element data.

For expression `var elem = mutablesArray[0]`, the compiler chooses to use `ldelem`.